# Disabled SID from backend but still showing onlyon homepage

Tags: magento2

Runnning Magento 2.1.7, with php7.0

I disabled "Show SID on front end" in my Magento backend, but yet the home page of my site still shows www.mydomain.com/?SID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I tried doing this in my .htaccess file as recommended by other people:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that makes a 500 error "too many redirects".  Any ideas? Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} XXXXXXXXX
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pki-validation/xxxxxxxxx9]xxxxxxxxxComodo\xxxxxxx
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xxxxxxxxxxxxx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validationxxxxx Comodo\ xxxxxxxxxx
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !xxxxxxxxxxcpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xxxxxxxx.well-known/pki-validation/xxxxx
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: I think this might be a cache issue. Try to refresh it and check

Comment: i have refreshed the cache 10000 times. Its not. Its happening on all my Magento 2 installations. Showing an SID just on the homepage, even though I have disabled it from the admin. So weird. Help anyone ?